# How does python functions calls that do not have class type or object in front work? example: len(s)

Tags: python, java

Coming from a Java background, I don't understand how python function like len(s) works.

As far as I know, in java, functions either need a class name or an object of a class type to be called. (ex: Collections.sort(a), name.age()).

Collections.sort(a) works as there is a sort function inside Collections class and name.age() works as java knows that name's class has an age function inside it.

How does python function like len(s) work?

Comment: It's just a top level function. They don't exist in Java, but do in Python.

Comment: It's a bit like the default package in Java.  Normally you put all your classes in a package, but you don't have to.  You can have class names floating about that aren't in any package.  Same idea with Python.  The functions are just names that are outside of any class, they don't have a class name associated with them.  I suppose you could think of them as static methods with an empty class name.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html -- as it describes, these functions are "always available". Python isn't Java; and I'm not sure what kind of _actual technical problem_ you have, since you do understand that these functions _are_ in fact always available, and so you're already capable of writing code that uses them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I thought there was something I do not know going on in python.

Comment: Please be sure you describe the "actual problem that you face" (quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) so there's something that can be concretely determined to be solved in determining which answer you're given is correct; such a problem is required for a question to be on-topic here.